# How does Entity Framework Migrations know which version the database is at?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework 5 code first, I'm wondering how EF Migrations decides that the target database is at a certain migration version? That is, I've emptied my database (deleted all tables) and am trying to re-do the initial migration via the following command (in the PM console): `update-database -targetmigration 201212011907118_Initial`. `update-database` then responds with 'Target database is already at version 201212011907118_Initial'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Code First Migrations maintains a table called 'dbo.__MigrationHistory' in which it stores metadata about applied migrations. This is a system table, which makes it difficult to e.g. delete. See [this post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/27/code-first-migrations-making-__migrationhistory-not-a-system-table) for reference.

Comment: My DB doesn't have the `__MigrationHistory` table yet but Migrations still tells me that the DB is already at my target version (it's not).